# Moshi custom adapter convert json mirror class to another

Tags: json, kotlin, moshi

In the Moshi documentation it states the ability to create a class that mirrors the shape of the JSON and then a custom adapter to tell it how to convert that class to another in the desired shape. I'm trying to do that, but it's as if the custom adapter isn't being executed.

My custom adapter looks like this:

```
class LocationJsonAdapter {

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(locationJson: LocationJson): Location {
        val location = Location()

        location.city.name = locationJson.city.name.en
        location.country.name = locationJson.country.name.en
        location.continent.name = locationJson.continent.name.en

        location.subdivisions.forEachIndexed {index, subdivision ->
            subdivision.name = locationJson.subdivisions[index].name.en
        }

        return location;
    }
}
```

I'm adding the adapter to Moshi here

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).add(LocationJsonAdapter()).build()
val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<Location> = moshi.adapter(Location::class.java)

val location: Location? = jsonAdapter.fromJson(data)
println(location)
```

If I understand the documentation correctly, it's supposed to convert the json to a `LocationJson` object and use the custom adapter to then convert the `LocationJson` object into a `Location` object. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding the custom adapter to the Moshi builder, the `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()` always has to go last. Adding it last fixed the issue

`val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(LocationJsonAdapter()).add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()`